# Systemverilog code error: near "" gmii_interface": Syntax error, unexpected IDENTIFIER, expecting class

Tags: verilog, system-verilog, uvm

I see a compile error:

```
// near " gmii_interface": Syntax error, unexpected IDENTIFIER, expecting class"//
```

in Model SIM when i compile the following testcase.sv code:

```
`include "D:/users/rajesh/GMII/interface.sv"
`include "D:/users/rajesh/GMII/environment.sv"

program testcase(gmiIInterface tx_intf);
environment env;

initial begin
    $display("\n########################################################");
    $display("#############     Start Verification    ##################");
    env = new(tx_intf);

    env.build();
    env.reset();
    env.start();
    env.waitforend();
    env.report();

    $display("\#############     End Verification    ###################");
    $display("\#########################################################");
end
endprogram: testcase
```

the corresponding interface.sv file code is below:

```
//Component Name: Interface
// Date: June 14, 2014

  interface gmii_Interface;
    logic tx_en;
    logic tx_er;
    logic tx_clk;
    logic [7:0] tx_data;
    logic rx_en;
    logic rx_er;
    logic rx_clk;
    logic [7:0] rx_data;
  endinterface : gmii_Interface
```

I'm a SV beginner, any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

`gmiIInterface` is not the same as `gmii_Interface`.